# Devise not asking for extra fields on sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I'm new to Devise, was advised against using my own authentication and use this instead since it's the standard for Rails apps and I'm having a hard time with it.

I'm trying to get users to signup to my site but I need to ask for more fields than the Devise defaults. I added this to my applications controller:

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:login, :username, :email, :password, :remember_me) }
end
```

Yet still only the email, password and confirmation show up. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you add those fields in your sign_up view (`devise/registrations/new.html.erb`) code?

Comment: Where are they located? Right now it's just the Devise default views, should I generate my own views when using Devise?

Comment: I don't see that devise folder in my project structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `rails generate devise:views` to add devise views in your application code for customization.

After running this command a folder would be created in `your_application/app/views` directory named `devise`. It will contain all the devise views which you can then customize as per your requirement.

For example: To add new fields on sign up page, you would need to customize `your_application/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb` view.

Comment: I got Could not find generator devise:views.

Comment: Make sure you have added `devise` gem in your `Gemfile` and run `bundle install`

Comment: Worked now, must have had a typo. Is it recommendable to create only the views for my Devise models? (rails generate devise:views MODEL)

Comment: If you are going to have separate devise models say `users` and `admins` and you need different customized views for them only in that case you should do `rails generate devise:views MODEL` else use the regular default views with `rails generate devise:views`

Comment: The [rails-devise example application](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-devise) from the RailsApps project gives a good example of adding extra fields to an application with Devise. I've also written a [Rails Devise Tutorial](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-devise/) that covers the topic. The [RailsLayout gem](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails_layout) will give you more attractive views, if you use Bootstrap or Foundation, than what you get with the Devise views generator.